# Shader - Convert vector into scalar

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx, glsl, hlsl

I am trying to convert a half3 as a simple half but I am facing an issue. As for an example half3(1, 0, 0) give me white but half3(0, 1, 0) gives me black.

How can I convert properly a half3 to a simple black and white half value

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of formulae for [converting colour to black and white](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale). Furthermore, the programmer might mean something else when converting a vector into a scalar (length would be a common example). The shader compiler keeps things as simple as possible, just taking the first value in the vector, in your example.

Experiment with different ways to get a black and white that looks good in your situation. Some examples might be:

`scalar = max(vector.r, max(vector.g, vector.b));`

OR

`scalar = (vector.r + vector.g + vector.b) * 0.333;`

OR

`scalar = length(vector) / 1.73205080757; // sqrt(3), which is the length of vector(1,1,1)`

OR go for one of the formulae in that [Wikipedia article I linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) that emulates black and white film.